# Qual a maneira correta de importar funções de outros pacotes no python?

Tags: python

Se eu for criar um pacote do python, definirei um arquivo `setup.py` que tem mais ou menos esse formato:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='funniest',
      version='0.1',
      description='The funniest joke in the world',
      url='http://github.com/storborg/funniest',
      author='Flying Circus',
      author_email='flyingcircus@example.com',
      license='MIT',
      packages=['funniest'],
      install_requires=[
          'markdown',
      ],
      zip_safe=False)
```

Existe alguma regra de boa prática de como se referir, no código, aos pacotes declarados como dependências?

Por exemplo em um arquivo do meu pacote, devo usar `import markdown` no começo.
Ou, quando for usar uma função do pacote `markdown` devo usar `markdown.x()`.

Vou explicar a motivação da pergunta. Em `R` o equivalente ao `import` é o `library` no entanto esta função possui side-effects (ela carrega todas as funções para o ambiente global do usuário) e não deve ser usada dentro de pacotes. No `python` não sei como é, por isso estou perguntado. (Leia isso antes de votar para fechar)

Comment: Você quer **"obrigar"** a pessoa que usa o seu pacote a executar o `markdown.x()` (por exemplo) quando importar o pacote?

Comment: Não, estou querendo saber qual a melhor forma de se referir às funções de um pacote dependente dentro do código do meu pacote. No R por exemplo, dentro de um pacote sempre usamos pacote_dependente::funcao() dentro do codigo de um pacote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse caso é com relação à uso normal de pacotes do Python mesmo.
Como seu pacote tem dependências elas serão instaladas com um pacote normal, com isso terão seu modo de importar normal como se você tivesse desenvolvendo um programa qualquer.

Ai entra os casos de importação padrão do Python.
Se você for usar somente alguma função de determinado pacote , por exemplo, do pacote `math` vai usar somente a `sqrt` então importa somente ela, e não tudo.

```
from math import sqrt
```

Mas tem a forma onde se importa todo o pacote `import math` e ao longo do script usa-se `math.funcao` para especificar qual deseja.

No seu caso para funções internas dos pacotes recomenda-se importar somente elas..

```
from pacote import funcao
```